# How to take only some values above a cutoff in a column

Tags: awk, cut

I have a file with 12 columns. In the 10th column I have values ranging from 0-100. However, I just need those values that are above 80. Rest, I want to be filtered out. may I know which command should I use?

example,

```
|Best_Hit_ARO|      |Best_Identities|
|------------|      |---------------|
|OXA-900     |      |      97.78    |
|qacJ        |      |      39.62    |
|adeF        |      |      67.78    |
```

So, like in this example, if Best-identities is my 10th column how do I keep only the values that are above 80, in this example, only 97.78.

P.S. It is a .tsv file and I want the results to go into a new-file.tsv. I just created this table here so that you all can visualize it with ease. Otherwise, it is a tsv file

Comment: Better add sample input and expected output

Comment: If you use `cat` to view your data, is what you show in the question what you see on the screen?

Comment: Regarding `I just created this table here so that you all can visualize it with ease` - feel free to ADD such a graphic to your question, but it's vastly more important that you show some actual sample input/output that we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with. As-is we don't even know if you want the column header included in the output or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is tab-delimited and contains the headers shown in the question:

```bash
$ cat file
Best_Hit_ARO    Best_Identities
OXA-900 97.78
qacJ    39.62
adeF    67.78
```

Then we may use e.g. [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to filter out (extract) the records where the `Best_Identities` field is strictly greater than 80 like so:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv filter '$Best_Identities > 80' file
Best_Hit_ARO    Best_Identities
OXA-900 97.78
```

This uses the `filter` operation of Miller to remove records that do not fulfil the given criteria.

It is not necessary to know that `Best_Identities` is the 2nd (or 10th, or whatever) field in each record, as Miller knows what each field is called and allows us to access it by name.

Using `awk` to get the header line and all other lines whose 2nd tab-delimited field is strictly greater than 80 could be done as so:

```bash
$ awk -F '\t' 'NR == 1 || $2 > 80' file
Best_Hit_ARO    Best_Identities
OXA-900 97.78
```

The cryptic code `NR == 1 || $2 > 80` is a boolean test that checks whether the current line is the first line of input (`NR == 1`) or whether the value in the second field is strictly greater than 80 (`$2 > 80`).  If the test is *true*, the current record is outputted.

Change `$2` to whatever index your actual data field has.

If you want the output of any of there commands to go into a new filename, then redirect the command into a new filename using `>some_new_name`.

You tagged your question with [cut](/questions/tagged/cut), but using `cut` is not possible here since that utility can't do filtering on values and since it, unless you select to cut *all* fields, would remove data that you would likely want to retain.